# Solving $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 h(x)f(z) \, dz$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was doing my math homework then i got stuck with solving the following equation,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 h(x)f(z)\,dz$$

I cannot deal with this equation, can anyone here help me out please?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to look at an example:

$h(x)= x$ and $f(z)= \sin z$. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_0^1 h(x) f(z)\; dz&= \dfrac{d}{dx} \int_0^1 x \sin z \;dz \\
&=\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(x \int_0^1 \sin z \;dz\right) \\
&=\int_0^1 \sin z \;dz \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} x \\
&= \int_0^1 \sin z \;dz \cdot 1 \\
&= \int_0^1 \sin z \;dz
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice we use the fact that $x$ is not the variable you're integrating with respect to in the integral, so just like a constant, such as $\pi, 2, -18$, etc, we can factor it out. But then the integral is just a constant with respect to the $x$ derivative, and we can put it out, just like we could taking the derivatives of $2x$, $\pi x^2$, etc. So using the fact that $h(x)$ is only a function of $x$ (notice it's the only variable involved), we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_0^1 h(x) f(z)\; dz&= \dfrac{d}{dx} h(x) \int_0^1 f(z)\; dz \\
&= \left(\int_0^1 f(z)\; dz\right) \left(\dfrac{d}{dx} h(x) \right) \\
&= \left(\int_0^1 f(z)\; dz\right) \cdot h'(x) \\
&= h'(x) \int_0^1 f(z)\; dz
\end{aligned}
$$
That is, assuming $h(x)$ is differentiable.

Comment: In the last line surely you mean "assuming $h$ is differentiable"

Comment: @peek-a-boo I do not see a difference - in terms of the English meaning. As written, I read it as, "You get XXX --- assuming $h'(x)$ is differentiable." Akin to how one might say, "You will get rich investing in this company; that is, assuming you invest in it." Perhaps others may read this differently?

Comment: I interpret "$h$ is differentiable" to mean the original function is differentiable i.e the first derivative $h'$ exists, whereas "$h'$ is differentiable" means the first derivative is differentiable and hence the second derivative exists, which is certainly not what you intended (after all the existence of second derivative is not at all needed here)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh! Yes! I 1000% agree. I thought the harumph was in the putting the assumption after having used it - not noting that I typed $h'(x)$ instead of $h(x)$. I was focused on the existence of $h'(x)$ and hence typed it rather than $h(x)$. Thank you for catching the typo!

Answer (score 0):

If $h(x)$ does not change as $z$ changes then you have
$$
\int_0^1 h(x) f(z) \, dz = h(x) \int_0^1 f(z)\,dz.
$$
And if $\int_0^1 f(z)\,dz$ does not change as $x$ changes, then
$$
\frac d {dx} \left( h(x) \int_0^1 f(z) \, dz\right) = \left(\frac d {dx} h(x) \right) \cdot \int_0^1 f(z) \,dz.
$$

Your phrase "solving the following equation" is wrong. This is about evalutating an expression, not solving an equation.